# I tried to vote on an answer; it says that I've already voted, but there's no indication I have

Tags: support, voting

I posted a question on Server Fault, and looked at my profile to realise that I only had a 75% accept rate.  So I went through looking for which question/s had missed out.

It turned out it was this one: [Set up basic Windows Authentication to connect to SQL Server 2008 from a small, trusted network](https://serverfault.com/questions/123673/set-up-basic-windows-authentication-to-connect-to-sql-server-2008-from-a-small-t)

Since the only answer was unhelpful, I went to downvote it.  There was no indication that I'd placed a vote previously (no up or down arrow overlaying the vote counts) - yet when I clicked the "down" arrow, I received a message saying "You last voted on this in April, you can't change your vote unless it is edited."  But I haven't voted, as far as I can see!

[alt text http://img291.imageshack.us/img291/8213/voted.png](http://img291.imageshack.us/img291/8213/voted.png)

Comment: I downvoted it for you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You voted at a earlier time and then canceled your vote. The system still retains the record of your vote.

Comment: isn't it un-wanted behavior?